# passing model to web api in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML form which has the following values:

```
 <input ng-model="person.id"/><br/>
 <input ng-model="person.name" /><br />
 <input ng-model="person.lastname" /><br />
 <button ng-click="callAPI()">Call API</button>
```

When clicked I call this function

```
 $scope.callAPI = function () {

    var person = {
        id: $scope.person.id,
        name: $scope.person.name,
        lastname: $scope.person.lastname
    };

    $http.post('/api/save/SavePerson', person).success(function (data) {
        $scope.returnValue = data;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving person! " + data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
};
```

I'm trying to pass it to my `SavePerson` method within my API as shown here:

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void SavePerson([FromBody]PersonModel person)
    {
        var dooda = string.Empty;
    }
```

The `PersonModel` looks like this :

```
  public class PersonModel
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
  }
```

However when I click `"CallAPI()"` and hit the break point within `SavePerson` the `person` model  is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to post a config object, and put your person as the "data" property.

```
$http.post('/api/save/SavePerson', {data:person})
```

This should get it into the body for you.

Comment: Worked, thanks I'll accept the answer in ten minutes,

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Never ever read $scope on your controller. This will make things really dificulty to test in the future and will not encapsulate the 'function of the function'. Use this instead:

```
<button ng-click="callAPI(person)">Call API</button>
```

On your controller,

```
$scope.callAPI = function (person) {
```

and you won't need to populate the person object. To your http request, you tried to access the wrong object. You'll receive a 'response' object that contains a data object. And you may change a bit your code to match the new $http request using .then instead of .success and .error.

```
$http.post('/api/save/SavePerson', person)

  .then( function (response) { //Called on success.
    $scope.returnValue = response.data;

  }, function (response) {  //Called on error
    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving person! " + response.data;
    $scope.loading = false;
  });
```

Try this and tell me if it works. :)